# Does Salesforce DX support Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, continuous-integration

Is there any way to install Salesforce DX CLI on an Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance or does it only support Ubuntu? If it doesn't support the AMI OS, Is there anything on the roadmap? I need to the DX CLI to run automation scripts using Jenkins.

Comment: You can install SFDX on anything that supports Node.js/NPM. It's not limited to Ubuntu. I am not familiar with AMI Linux, though.

Answer (score 1):

We run Jenkins jobs using sfdx everyday on our AWS EC2 server, so the answer is yes :)

You can also use docker containers with sfdx installed on them, if you want something cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully install DX with Amazon Linux AMI using the list of commands in the [Setup guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sfdx_setup.pdf).